# Invoke method in child component when the component is changed dynamically from the parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple component hierarchy, in which there is one parent component, which contains the following template `<div><component :is="current"></component></div>` and two child components, which are dynamically 'switched' out, via the value of `current`.

The logic for the 'switching' of components is being handled in the parent component. However, when I try to execute a method in the second child component (in response to an event emitted from the first child component, being listened to in the parent component, and altering the value of `current` in the parent component) through the `mounted` lifecycle hook, the expected result is not observed.

Essentially,  I cannot find a decent way of invoking a child component's methods when that component is 'switched' in as the current component in the parent component.

I have realistically looked at using the `$refs` and `$children`properties on the instance, but these do not seem to be of any assistance. I have also reasoned using the event system. I usually 'define' an event listener in the `mounted` lifecycle hook, however, I refer to the 'issue' of using the lifecycle hooks

What is the usual approach to this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options that immediately come to mind for child components invoking methods on being the "current" child component:

1) Using the `mounted` lifecycle hook. In order for this to work, you must be using `v-if` in order to conditionally display the child component, otherwise the child component will not trigger the `mounted` lifecycle hook. Otherwise, if you're using `v-show` or some other mechanism for conditionally displaying the child component, the `mounted` hook will only ever trigger once.

2) Using watched properties. In lieu of the above, you could do something like the following:

```
<child-component :target_prop="current"></child-component>

Vue.component('child-component', {
    . . .,
    props: ['target_prop'],
    watch: {
        target_prop: function() {
            if(this.target_prop == your_expected_value) {
                //execute the desired method for this component
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is, of course, just a proof-of-concept example and there are plenty of alternative ways to use the watched properties to your advantage.

I've also heard of using a "bus" to handle inter-component communication, but I don't believe it would be any better than the above two solutions (and is arguably worse).

Personally, I prefer the `mounted` lifecycle hook approach, though there's the caveat that any "settings" or data in your child components will be lost on switching between them (although you could also emit a settings object on destruction and store/restore those settings as needed, but that could get messy). You'll have to make the final judgment on which approach better suits your needs and which consequences you're more comfortable dealing with.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Comment: I had some troubles with watching the prop, am I unsure as to why. However, I found a 'lifecycle' hook- ```activated``` that was exactly what I was after. It seems that ```activated``` is called when a component goes from ```inactive``` to ```active```, this behaviour is observed when 'switching' components, vie the ```:is``` property of a component.